# Accessing the locale information in nextjs i18n

Tags: next.js, i18next

according to nextjs documentation

> You can access the locale information via the Next.js router. For example, using the useRouter() hook the following properties are available:  locale contains the currently active locale. locales contains all configured locales.

but the problem is useRouter hook no-longer is supported ; only usenavigation is replaced;
but on the other tis new useRouter doesnt return locale; how can i access it ??

according to nextjs documentation

> You can access the locale information via the Next.js router. For example, using the useRouter() hook the following properties are available:  locale contains the currently active locale. locales contains all configured locales.

but the problem is useRouter hook no-longer is supported ; only usenavigation is replaced;
but on the other tis new useRouter doesnt return locale; how can i access it ?

Comment: take a look at the documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization